# Custom terminal function to change text case

Tags: command-line, text, text-processing

I'm looking for a custom terminal function `change_case` that will function as below to help me manage my titles on my website:

```
change_case [option] "string"

option:
    upper - STRING TO UPPERCASE
    lower - string to lowercase
    sentence - Uppercase first letter of every word, others to lowercase
    custom - String to Sentence Case except These Words if they appear as the 1st letter:
        [in,by,with,of,a,to,is,and,the]
```

---

#### Example title - [How can I make the login screen appear instead of logging me in automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493004/how-can-i-make-the-login-screen-appear-instead-of-logging-me-in-automatically)

**upper:** HOW CAN I MAKE THE LOGIN SCREEN APPEAR INSTEAD OF LOGGING ME IN AUTOMATICALLY?

**lower:** how can i make the login screen appear instead of logging me in automatically?

**sentence:** How Can I Make The Login Screen Appear Instead Of Logging Me In Automatically?

**custom:** How Can I Make the Login Screen Appear Instead of Logging Me in Automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not too complicated:

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `change_case` (no extension) in `~/bin` (you may have to create the directory). *Make the script executable*
2. You may have to log out/in, especially if the directory did not yet exist (or alternatively, run: `source ~/.profile`)
3. Open a terminal window, test it by running the command:

   ```
   change_case custom this is a test case to see if all in the script works
   ```

   output:

   ```
   This is a Test Case to See If All in the Script Works
   ```

I tested it with all options from your question (upper, lower, sentence, custom) and all should work as your example.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

string = sys.argv[2:]
opt = sys.argv[1]

excluded = ["in","by","with","of","a","to","is","and","the"]

if opt == "lower":
    print((" ").join(string).lower())
elif opt == "upper":
    print((" ").join(string).upper())
elif opt == "sentence":
    print((" ").join(string).title())
elif opt == "custom":
    line = []
    for s in string:
        s = s.title() if not s in excluded else s
        line.append(s)
    print((" ").join(line))
```

Comment: I think you mean `~/.bin` directory, right?

Comment: @Parto  Nono, `~/bin` is in $PATH by default, not `~/.bin` as far as I know.

Comment: Cool. Lemme test it out.

Comment: I think I should learn python now...thanks all the same.

Comment: @Parto I love python, it's almost thinking aloud on (virtual) paper.

Comment: I'm really good in PHP (or so I think) - and I'm not talking about CMS'es - so learning python shouldn't be that hard...riiight?

Comment: Another one python's the dust...  ;-)